# Merge arrays made in a loop PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, array-merge

I have a array that, 3 repeats from the same week, but 3 differents users that have your totals separately:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'week' => '1'
      'user' => 'Oswaldo Aranha'
      'totals' => 'value'
  1 => 
    array
      'week' => '1'
      'user' => 'Protogenes'
      'totals' => 'value'
  2 => 
    array
      'week' => '1'
      'user' => 'Rego Barros'
      'totals' => 'value'
  3 => 
    array
      'week' => '2'
      'user' => 'Oswaldo Aranha'
      'totals' => 'value'
  4 => 
    array
      'week' => '2'
      'user' => 'Protogenes'
      'totals' => 'value'
  5 => 
    array
      'week' => '2'
      'user' => 'Rego Barros'
      'totals' => 'value'
  ...
```

I wanna to unify the week in one array, with the 3 users and your totals. Like this:

```
array 
  0 => 
  array 
    'week' => '1'
    'Oswaldo Aranha' => 'value'
    'Protogenes' => 'value'
    'Rego Barros' => 'value'
  1 => 
  array 
    'week' => '2'
    'Oswaldo Aranha' => 'value'
    'Protogenes' => 'value'
    'Rego Barros' => 'value'

  2 => 
  array 
    'week' => '3'
    'Oswaldo Aranha' => 'value'
    'Protogenes' => 'value'
    'Rego Barros' => 'value'
  ...
```

I'm trying using `array_merge()`, `array_combine()`, `array_whatever()` but doesn' work. How i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = [
    [
        'week' => '1',
        'user' => 'Oswaldo Aranha',
        'totals' => 'value'
    ],
    [
        'week' => '1',
        'user' => 'Protogenes',
        'totals' => 'value'
    ],
    [
        'week' => '1',
        'user' => 'Rego Barros',
        'totals' => 'value'
    ],
    [
        'week' => '2',
        'user' => 'Oswaldo Aranha',
        'totals' => 'value',
    ],
    [
        'week' => '2',
        'user' => 'Protogenes',
        'totals' => 'value'
    ]
];
function combineWeeks($array) {
    $results = [];
    for($i = 0;$i < count($array);$i++) {
        $results[$array[$i]['week']][$array[$i]['user']] = $array[$i]['totals'];
        $results[$array[$i]['week']]['week'] = $array[$i]['week'];
    }
    $combined = [];
    foreach($results as $key => $value) {
        $combined[] = $results[$key];
    }
    return $combined;
}
```

Usage:

```
$combinedArray = combineWeeks($array);
print_r($combinedArray);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Oswaldo Aranha] => value
            [week] => 1
            [Protogenes] => value
            [Rego Barros] => value
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Oswaldo Aranha] => value
            [week] => 2
            [Protogenes] => value
        )

)
```

Comment: one more question. With this new array, how i show the values of `Protogenes` for example?

Comment: Loop it with foreach. Depends on how you want to access it: `$array[0]['Protogenes'];`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `array_merge();`

```
$arr=array_merge ( $array[0],$array[1] ,$array[3]);
```

i hope this will help you :)

for extra info this link will help you :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: thanks for reply, but the first array example have a lot of sub-arrays, is not specific. Every month, have your weeks... using your example, i dont know how many arrays i have to put in `array_merge()`.

Comment: you can iterate through the main array and check the values of the week in each sub array and you merge the previous result with the new result like the concatenation principle    :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no php-function doing it for you. Just do it your own:

```
$in = $array;
$out = [];
foreach ($in as $curIn) {
    if ( ! isset ($out[$curIn["week"]])) {
        $out[$curIn["week"]] = [];
    }
    $out[$curIn["week"]][$curIn["user"]] = $curIn["totals"];
}
```

That's it.